# UnsupportedOperationException thrown for webflux resource

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm trying to play some sample code like this:

```
@GetMapping("/unsupport")
  public Mono<Void> unsupport(ServerWebExchange exchange) {

    return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap("unsupport".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));


  }
```

And then I got UnsupportedOperationException with below stack:

> at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.java:1451)   at
>   org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.setContentType(HttpHeaders.java:854)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.codec.EncoderHttpMessageWriter.updateContentType(EncoderHttpMessageWriter.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.codec.EncoderHttpMessageWriter.write(EncoderHttpMessageWriter.java:100)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.codec.EncoderHttpMessageWriter.write(EncoderHttpMessageWriter.java:167)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.writeBody(AbstractMessageWriterResultHandler.java:146)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ResponseEntityResultHandler.lambda$handleResult$2(ResponseEntityResultHandler.java:174)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:141)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1080)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1080)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1080)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipCoordinator.signal(MonoZip.java:241)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onNext(MonoZip.java:323)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1637)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip$ZipInner.onSubscribe(MonoZip.java:312)
>     at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54)  at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:128)    at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60)     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3080)     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:97)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:222)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:222)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:1123)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenAcceptInner.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:300)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:185)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:251)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:133)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.ignoreDone(MonoIgnoreThen.java:185)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreInner.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:234)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ChannelSendOperator$WriteCompletionBarrier.onComplete(ChannelSendOperator.java:373)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreElements$IgnoreElementsSubscriber.onComplete(MonoIgnoreElements.java:80)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatIterable$ConcatIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatIterable.java:115)
>     at
>   reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.WriteResultPublisher$State.publishComplete(WriteResultPublisher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.WriteResultPublisher.publishComplete(WriteResultPublisher.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractListenerWriteFlushProcessor$State$3.writeComplete(AbstractListenerWriteFlushProcessor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractListenerWriteFlushProcessor$State$WriteResultSubscriber.onComplete(AbstractListenerWriteFlushProcessor.java:374)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.WriteResultPublisher$State.publishComplete(WriteResultPublisher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.WriteResultPublisher.publishComplete(WriteResultPublisher.java:69)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractListenerWriteProcessor.changeStateToComplete(AbstractListenerWriteProcessor.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractListenerWriteProcessor.access$400(AbstractListenerWriteProcessor.java:44)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractListenerWriteProcessor$State$3.onWritePossible(AbstractListenerWriteProcessor.java:289)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.AbstractListenerWriteProcessor.onWritePossible(AbstractListenerWriteProcessor.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletServerHttpResponse$ResponseBodyWriteListener.onWritePossible(ServletServerHttpResponse.java:238)
>     at org.apache.coyote.Response.onWritePossible(Response.java:700)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The HttpHeaders seems to be created in an immutable way.

Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug?

Thanks

Leon